# More efficient method of calculation genotype or phenotype ratios rather than doing a trihybrid punnett square or forked-line method?

Tags: genetics

Is there any other more efficient method of predicting ratios of offspring phenotypes or genotypes than doing a trihybrid Punnett square or forked-line diagram? Or are those two methods really the only solution. This is for a question dealing with unlinked traits.

[image]